# Do Google OR-tools support using multiple 3rdparty solvers and switching them at runtime?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint-programming, or-tools

I need to give the user the ability to choose solver **at runtime**, so this is crucial for the decision if using Google OR-Tools would be a good fit.

Couldn't find the answer to this question in the documentation, so thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Imho you can switch at [runtime](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/linear_solver/linear_solver.h#L234), but need compile-time [interface-building](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/dbac8c324d1fa3d37ed992174aa4c0fcc48cd673/ortools/linear_solver/linear_solver.cc#L323) (and not of those commercial interfaces are build into the binary releases). As your question is pretty sparse, it's unclear if that's working out for you. If not, checkout out [Coin OSI](https://github.com/coin-or/Osi)

Comment: Maybe for MIP or LP, but I dont think you can use another solver with the CP or routing interface

Comment: I'll clarify: for example, for LP/MIP is it possible to switch in runtime between GLOP, COIN, SCIP, Gurobi and CPLEX?

Comment: Wasn't this answered in above's comment?

Comment: @sascha It was, although it only shows that the API is there, but not that it actually works. I'd hope for someone to have a hands-on experience doing this.